Resources for learning about graphs of rational functions?
I'm trying to learn how to create rational functions whose graphs have particular qualities. For example, I've learned how to create functions with linear asymptotes or non-linear asymptotes, but there are other things I haven't figured out how to do.
Here are some examples of the kind of question I'm interested in. I've included the graph of $\frac{2}{-x^2 + 2x}$ so that it'll be easier for me to ask these questions.

The middle branch has a local minimum of $(1,2)$, but is there a way of "moving" the minimum to a point of my choosing? Is there general way of choosing where the local extremum of a branch is located?

What determines the size of the gap in the range? There's a gap in the range of this rational function, in $[0, 2)$, between the horizontal asymptote at $y=0$ and the minimum of the middle branch. How can I control the size of this gap? (It's actually worse, I have no idea how to calculate the size of this gap (given an equation for the function) or even determine whether or not a gap exists somewhere in the range.)

How can I control whether or not a branch opens up or down in a rational function?


Where can I learn more about this kind of thing? I'm interested in learning about the shape of rational functions in general, but I'm not quite sure where to look for this kind of info.
To be clear, I would like resources for learning how to answer these kinds of questions myself, not necessarily the answers to these questions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
